# Как сделать так, чтобы по ссылке перешло на другую страницу + по якорю на этой открывшейся странице?

Tags: javascript, html, css

На главной странице сайта при клике на раздел "Услуги", страница прокручивается вниз к якорю (этот раздел находится на главной странице). Мне надо, чтобы, находясь на другой странице сайта, при нажатии в шапке на "Услуги", оно переходило на главную страницу и перемещалось к якорю к соответствующему блоку.

Answer (score 3):

Надо просто прописать в адресе ссылки якорь:

```html
<a href="/#services">Услуги</a>
```